# Weblogic increase memory

Tags: java, weblogic, permgen, weblogic12c

How do I increase the memory used by my Weblogic (Java). While starting the server from eclipse it shows a message that `JAVA Memory arguments: -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m`. I couldn't understand from where is it taking that value from. After sometime the Weblogic server fails because of low permgen space.

I added startup arguments from console but that doesn't have any effect. Can you help me from where is it taking the memory values from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you configure a "Server" in Eclipse for WebLogic, you select a domain directory (for local).  That domain directory contains the startup scripts that Eclipse will use to start the WebLogic Server.  These are the same scripts that you would use if you started the server if you did it without Eclipse.  Inside the domain directory is a folder called "bin".  In the "bin" directory, locate the setDomainEnv file (.sh for unix, or .cmd for Windows).  In that file, alter the memory settings to suite your needs.

Based on the error message you mentioned in your question, I would increase both the PermSize and MaxPermSize settings to 512m.  For PermSize and MaxPermSize, there are two locations each by default in a simple WLS installation, one for 32-bit, and another for 64-bit.  It won't hurt to change them both.  But if you know which JVM architecture you are running, you can change the one that applies to your environment.

Comment: +1 for `<$WEBLOGIC_HOME>\user_projects\domains\<your_domain>\bin\setDomainEnv.cmd`

Answer (score 7):

You will have a file setDomainEnv.cmd/setDomainEnv.sh under your server bin folder. this file contains

```
 set MEM_MAX_PERM_SIZE_64BIT=-XX:MaxPermSize=512m

set MEM_MAX_PERM_SIZE_32BIT=-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

Max and Min memory values as

```
if "%JAVA_VENDOR%"=="Sun" (
    set WLS_MEM_ARGS_64BIT=-Xms256m -Xmx512m
    set WLS_MEM_ARGS_32BIT=-Xms256m -Xmx512m
) else (
    set WLS_MEM_ARGS_64BIT=-Xms512m -Xmx512m
    set WLS_MEM_ARGS_32BIT=-Xms512m -Xmx512m
)
```

You can update the values inside it.

Comment: Hi, I edited these settings but still no good. Do you have any reccommendation about this question? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27189991/wls-jvm-settings

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the previous two answers that are correct (modifying `setDomainEnv` and potentially `wl_server\common\bin\commEnv`), you can also modify servers individually if you are starting them with the nodemanager.

In the admin console navigate to:

```
Servers -> <server name> -> Server Start tab -> Arguments
```

Here you can set the JVM args you want for that server rather than making a blanket change in all servers to setDomainEnv

Comment: Hi name..just one question.Do you mean modifying setDomainEnv.cmd is fine ? irrespective of how many admin servers we have ?

Comment: Ideally you would use the answer I gave, setting memory for each server but depending on your environment it may be ok to use a blanket setting in setDomainEnv

Answer (score 3):

Looks like eclipse plugin adds it own USER_MEM_ARGS variable, so it should be rewritten using following approach:
Open following file:

```
$WL_HOME/user_projects/domains/mydomain/bin/setDomainEnv.sh
```

and add the next line to it (e.g. after help description)

```
USER_MEM_ARGS=$ECLIPSE_MEM_ARGS
```

Then, open weblogic server properties (double click at weblogic in servers view) and click "Open launch configuration". In a opened window select "Environment" and add new variable  ECLIPSE_MEM_ARGS with memory params as value, e.g.:

```
ECLIPSE_MEM_ARGS=-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

Save and check that server was applied new configuration.
P.S. Using this approach you can change/add memory params directly from eclipse.
P.S.S. In **Windows** you should use **setDomainEnv.cmd** file and added line should be:

```
set USER_MEM_ARGS=%ECLIPSE_MEM_ARGS%
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Weblogic12**:

Environment->Servers->[your_server]->Configuration/Server Start -> Arguments:

```
-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m
```

Restart the server:
Environment->Servers->[your_server]->Control/"Start/Stop" -> Suspend and then Start.

Check your memory:
Environment->Servers->[your_server]->Monitoring/Performance.